# what is the best way to flex align two items right and one left

Tags: html, css

This image given below is the result I am looking for.

[image]

I have the html as follows

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content1">1</div>
      <div class="content2">2</div>
      <div class="content3">3</div>
    </div>
```

here container is set to `display: flex`
I wanted to align the divs as follows.
I can give `justify-content: space-between`
but how to align the centre div closer to 3 with 10px distance from it.

I have several containers which is aligned row by row. So, in the end, it should look like this as image shown below.

[image]

I have given `margin-left` to div 2 but it doesn't order correctly with different div  having different width.

Comment: you can give content2  margin-left : auto

Comment: I think this is the best way

Comment: Multiple wasys can be used to achieve what you want. Here is another solution https://jsfiddle.net/b9wgaxo3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add another div around the 2 on the right, and then use margin to create space around all of the div's

```css
.container{
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between;
background: grey;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
}
.content1,
.content2,
.content3{
background: green;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 10px;
}
.align{
display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="content1">1</div>
      <div class="align">
        <div class="content2">2</div>
        <div class="content3">3</div>
      <div>
    </div>
```